# Why are web maps able to display features from a REST endpoint that is disabled?

Tags: web-mapping, arcgis-rest-api, web-service, map-service

Let's say I have web service **X**: *maps.example.com/servername/rest/services/folder/ServiceName/MapServer/0*

If I navigate to **X** in my browser's search bar, I get the following error:

```
{
    "Error": "Services Directory has been disabled",
    "Code": 403
}
```

However, when I add **X** into an ESRI web map using "Add data from the Web", everything displays fine. According to [this ESRI documentation](https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/server/10.3/administer/linux/disabling-the-services-directory.htm), one can disable a services directory. By my reasoning, this should prevent users from accessing or querying the data in the map or through an HTML page.

Why is it possible to add a service from a disabled directory to a web map? Is it a weird quirk with this particular **X** service, or does this have broader context?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation you link to is about the Services Directory functionality. Services Directory allows you to browse all your services through a normal browser. It is not about access to the underlying web services. To restrict access to your services you can look at the documentation here: https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/server/10.3/administer/linux/restricting-access-to-gis-web-services.htm

Comment: Ah, so there's a difference between the directory and the actual service. What does that difference boil down to?

Comment: I think Services Directory is just the marketing-ified name for documentation :) Services Directory documents the web services.